# i want to rewrite my custom plugin url

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am Working on wordpress plugin. and i have a form like this

```
    $action_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL .'/demo-url-rewrite/include/test.php';


   <form action="<?php echo $action_url; ?>" method="get" name="f1">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br />
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Save">
   </form>
```

when user submit a form and action is performed i want this url ::
http://mysite.com/Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/client/pranav-gandhi/

instead of this url ::

http://mysite.com/Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/wp-content/plugins/demo-url-rewrite/include/test.php?name=Pranav+Gandhi&b1=Save

so How can i overwrite url with worpress functionality.

thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need the URL? Such URLs are needed only if you want the search to be indexed. Example: [Check this](http://nakedoffice.com.au/search/companies/searchby/a). (That 'a' in the url comes from the search form in this page and the homepage)
The ideal way for parsing a form is to use the [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) action hook instead of setting the form action. If you still want the custom URL, let me know and I'll tell you a solution!

Edit:
Assuming only the client name will change.

URLS:

```
add_filter('init', 'add_page_rewrite_rules');
function add_page_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp;

    //this will hold the text field data
    $wp->add_query_var('client_name');

    //the actual rule
    add_rewrite_rule('^Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/client/(.*)?$','index.php?pagename=client-data&client_name=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Now make a WP page with slug as `client-data`. This is required for the rule to work. Make a page template, assign it to this page. Make sure the following 2 lines are in the page template.

```
global $wp, $wp_query;
$name = get_query_var('client_name');
```

The `$name` var will have the client name you pass in the URL, use it to do the processing as you would using the form data. You can either use jQuery to handle the form submit and redirect to this custom URL or you can use the `init` action to check the form submit and use a hard redirect to this URL. Using PHP the redirect URL should be

```
echo home_url('/Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/client/'.$_POST['name']);
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanx but i want custom url like i had given.

Comment: Kewl! Updating the answer...

Comment: What is the exact URL that you want?

Comment: http://mysite.com/Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/client/<client-name>/ this type of url i want. now i have this url :: http://mysite.com/Projects/demos/demo-url-rewrite/wp-content/plugins/demo-url-rewrite/include/test.php?name=Pranav+Gandhi&b1=Save

Comment: From this URL, which all parts are gonna stay constant, and which will change? I guess only the client name will change

Comment: yes client name will change

Comment: Sorry but its not working for me...

Comment: Did u try all the steps?

Comment: yes i follow all steps.

Comment: Oops... I forgot to mention one important step after you add new URL rules. After you do the above steps, go to `Settings > Permalinks` and just hit the save button... It'll work!